# How do I drag and drop a label to autocomplete textfield?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6

I want to drag and drop a label or something that will autocomplete the UITextfield. For example if I have an empty textfield and I drag a label with text "hello world" on top of the textfield, the textfield will have "hello world" as its text. Does anyone know how I can do this? Is a UILabel the best choice to use? or perhaps a UIButton could work?

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve this problem yourself? This requires several steps. Which  don't you know how to do? Do you know how to drag a view? Do you know how to tell when one view overlaps (is on top of) another view?

Comment: @rdelmar I'm not too sure of the steps I should be taking. Right now, I have a regular UITextfield and a label that I've enabled to drag/move around the screen. What do you suggest I do next?

Comment: When you end the drag, check if the label overlaps the text field using 
CGRectIntersectsRect. If it does, get the string from the label, and set that string on the text field.

Comment: @rdelmar Figured it out! I ended up using CGRectContainsPoint. Thank so much!

Comment: @laura Did you solve the problem. If you have can you mark the answer accepted and upvote

Answer (score 0):

You better read the tutorial first  about IOS development. follow the tutorial

in this site `http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-course/`

For your question study the following link first then arise the questions

```
http://www.appcoda.com/hello-world-build-your-first-iphone-app/
http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-basic-how-does-the-hello-world-app-work/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   //get position
   // get label on that position
   [label removeFromSuperView];
   newLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init]; 
   [self.view addSubView:newLabel]; //positioned at label
}

touchesMoved {
   //getPosition
   newLabel.position = position;
}

touchesEnded {
   //getPosition.
   self.view.subviews; // loop and find which view has the position.

   UILabel *finalLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
   finalLabel.center = newLabel.center;

   [newLabel removeFromSuperView];

   [viewToBeDroppedOn addSubview:finalLabel];
}
```

Also Check this tutorial [Drag & Drop](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/simple-drag-and-drop-on-iphone/)